# jQuery vmap change zoom factor

Tags: jquery, jqvmap

When using [jqvmap](/questions/tagged/jqvmap), is there a possiblity to set a default zoom or scale factor?
I use the europe map and it looks better after one or two clicks on zoom in. 
The only way to set the the zoom is to set

```
enableZoom: true/false
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit source code in  `jquery.vmap.js`

Approximately 246 line of code.

```
this.rootGroup.setAttribute('transform', 'scale() translate()');
```

Just set whatever you want.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.